# can list.stream().sorted do with three canditions?

Tags: java, sorting, stream, comparator

I already sucess sort by follow implementation,

> if 'category' field equals, then compare 'sort' field, if 'category' field not equals, then compare 'id' field.

```
List<Contact> originContactList = ...;

originContactList.sort((contact1, contact2) -> {
    if (contact1.getCategory().compareTo(contact2.getCategory()) == 0) {
        return contact1.getSort().compareTo(contact2.getSort());
    } else {
        return contact1.getId().compareTo(contact2.getId());
    }
});
```

---

I want use java8 list.stream().sorted do the same as above code. Can it ?

> I can't do if 'category' field not equals, then compare 'id' field.

```
List<Contact> originContactList = ...;

originContactList.stream().sorted(
        Comparator
                .comparing(Contact::getCategory)
                .thenComparingLong(Contact::getSort)
)
...
```

Comment: Did you try it first?

Comment: Yes, I try first, I don't know how comparing id if the category is not equals, so I redo it without stream. @Javia1492

Comment: Instead of doing `.thenComparingLong()`, why not write a custom method to apply in the `comparing()` call. I.e. `comparing(Conact::getSort)` where `getSort()` compares the `category` and if they're not equal, compares the `id`?

Comment: You have already created correct comparator in the first nippet. What is stopping you from using the same comparator(literary copy/paste) as argument for `stream.sorted(...)`?

Comment: @Chaosfire I think he wants to use `.stream()` and the `Comparator` class rather than defining a custom comparator?

Comment: @MichaelMao So if *categories* are the same, you are using one field `sort` for comparison, otherwise another `id` ? Seems like you're breaking the general contract of the `compare()` method, and you might encounter a vied behavior.

Comment: Yes,  I thought there was a smarter way to do it, such as 'elseComparingLong'  or 'orComparingLong', I seems that it still need write a custom comprator. and thank to 
 @Chaosfire, you are right, I just find they are same arguments !

Comment: @Javia1492 Both first and second snippet are defining custom comparators, just different ways of doing it. Fist uses lambdas, second static methods of `Comparator`. The second approach can't achieve what the first is doing, which has downsides as explained in comments and answer.

Comment: Yes, I first thought is use LinkedHashmap or Treemap, but it is need more code, so I thought may be there have a more convenient way to do this. Now I found you are right, if create a new ccontact with categoryA, it will at the end of the list.@ 
Alexander Ivanchenko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the comparator from your first example with streams too:

```
List<Contact> originContactList = ...;

originContactList.stream().sorted(
    (contact1, contact2) -> {
    if (contact1.getCategory().compareTo(contact2.getCategory()) == 0) {
        return contact1.getSort().compareTo(contact2.getSort());
    } else {
        return contact1.getId().compareTo(contact2.getId());
    }
})
```

**But**: any comparator that you write has to obey one basic rule:

If it says that from three contacts `contactA`, `contactB` and `contactC` the `contactA` should be sorted before `contactB` and `contactB` should be sorted before `contactC` then it **must** also say that `contactA` should be sorted before `contactC`.

Or in the words of the [JavaDoc of `Comparator.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)):

> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0`

With your comparator implementation it is easy to create three contacts that violate this rule.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I first thought is use LinkedHashmap or Treemap, but it is need more code, so I thought may be there have a more convenient way to do this. Now I found you are right, if create a new ccontact with categoryA, it will at the end of the list.@Thomas Kläger